# Is it possible to find dependence between $X$ and $Y$ from distribution of $X-Y$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

Consider $X,Y \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, I am exploring all the possible ways to find dependence. Correlation, Eye Balling from scatter plot are I think obvious methods.

I am trying to think in a different direction just to have a better understanding. So, When $Y$ is dependent on $X$ what would $X-Y$ distribution look like?
From what I am aware of $X-Y \sim \mathcal N(0,2)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Consider a distribution show in the graph below, I want to comment on dependence just from the graph [dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vZBv.png)

If this is not possible how can joint probability tell be about dependence.

Comment: Your question is a little vague.For one thing, it's not even clear if you are considering $X,Y$ to be jointly gaussian, or not (only marginally).

Comment: If they are jointly normal, then correlation tells the whole story of their dependence. If they are marginally normal but not jointly normal, then much more complicated modes of dependence can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}$You have $X,Y \sim N(0,1).$

You did not say anything about their **joint** distribution beyond that --- in particular whether they are jointly normally distributed.

If they are independent, then they are jointly normally distributed. In that case you have $\v(X-Y) = \v(X)+\v(Y) = 2,$ so $\operatorname{sd}(X-Y) = \sqrt 2.$

Suppose they are jointly normal but not independent, and the correlation is $\rho.$ Then
\begin{align}
\v(X-Y) & = \v(X)+\v(Y) - 2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) \\
& = \v(X) + \v(Y) - 2\rho\sqrt{\v(X)} \sqrt{\v(Y) } \\
& = 1 + 1 -2\rho.
\end{align}

Since $-1\le\rho\le1,$ we have $0 \le \v(X-Y) \le 4.$

So $X-Y\sim N(0,2-2\rho).$ Knowing the variance of $X-Y,$ you can find $\rho,$ and knowing $\rho$ you can find the variance of $X-Y.$

The distributions in the graph do not look normal except that the red one may be a crude approximation. Perhaps density estimation based on a small sample from a normally distributed population could have produced them.

It took me a while (20 seconds?) to suspect that the hyphens in the graphic might have been intended to be minus signs.
\begin{align}
\text{minus sign: } & X-Y \\[10pt]
\text{hyphen: } & X \text{ - } Y \\[10pt]
\text{hyphen: } & X \text{-} Y
\end{align}